# How to split/cut till specific path (directory path )of string in perl

Tags: perl, split, directory, path

Input : `"/abcd/prod/Cid/1234/Did"` or `"/abcd/prod/Cid/1234/Did/Pid/234"`

Output: `"/abcd/prod/Cid/1234/"`  (Only till 4th word, considering '/' is the delimiter)

How to slice and get above using perl

Answer (score 3):

As *one-liner* :

```
$ perl -F'/' -lane 'print join "/", @{F[0..4]}' <<< "/abcd/prod/Cid/1234/Did"
```

As a script :

```
while (<>) {
    chomp $_;
    my @F = split(m[/], $_, 0);
    print join('/', @F[0..4]), "\n";
}
```

### Output :

```
/abcd/prod/Cid/1234
```